# Cant find saved images on amazon s3 in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to use s3 for uploading images and saving them. This might sound stupid but I can't find the image/image url after upload even though I receive a 200 Ok response.

I have the following code to upload multipart files;

```
    public PutObjectResult uploadMultipart(MultipartFile multipart) throws IOException
        {
        byte[] contentBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(multipart.getInputStream());
        Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length);
        System.out.println(contentLength);
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
        byte[] resultByte = DigestUtils.md5(multipart.getInputStream());
        String streamMD5 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(resultByte));
        metadata.setContentMD5(streamMD5);
        metadata.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, "files/products/" + multipart.getOriginalFilename(), multipart.getInputStream(), metadata);
        putObjectRequest.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        PutObjectResult putObjectResult = amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

        IOUtils.closeQuietly(multipart.getInputStream());

        return putObjectResult;
        }
```

And then in my controller, I call it like this;

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public PutObjectResult upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFiles) throws IOException {
        return s3Wrapper.uploadMultipart(multipartFiles);
    }
```

I receive a 200 Ok with the following response

```
{
  "versionId": null,
  "expirationTime": null,
  "expirationTimeRuleId": null,
  "contentMd5": "znuCfIi9trlacd4DOmUdef==",
  "metadata": {
    "userMetadata": {},
    "httpExpiresDate": null,
    "expirationTime": null,
    "expirationTimeRuleId": null,
    "ongoingRestore": null,
    "restoreExpirationTime": null,
    "contentLength": 0,
    "lastModified": null,
    "contentType": null,
    "contentEncoding": null,
    "versionId": null,
    "etag": "ce7b827c88bdb6b9616c3e033a652197",
    "storageClass": null,
    "ssealgorithm": null,
    "ssecustomerAlgorithm": null,
    "ssecustomerKeyMd5": null,
    "contentMD5": null,
    "cacheControl": null,
    "rawMetadata": {
      "Content-Length": 0,
      "ETag": "ce7b827c88bdb6b9616c3e033a652197"
    },
    "contentDisposition": null,
    "instanceLength": 0,
    "serverSideEncryption": null,
    "sseawsKmsKeyId": null
  },
  "etag": "ce7b827c88bdb6b9616c3e033a652197",
  "ssealgorithm": null,
  "ssecustomerAlgorithm": null,
  "ssecustomerKeyMd5": null,
  "serverSideEncryption": null
}
```

But, I cant find my image. How do i get the image or the image url?

Comment: `metadata.setContentType("multipart/form-data");` Why are you not using the actual MIME type of the uploaded file?  Also, are the uploads visible in the S3 console?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thanks. I changed it to the mime type but same result. The content length of the uploads is 58095. But for some reason I dont understand, the cont length returned is 0.